# How can I turn a computer and wireless router into a small network with no Internet connection?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router

I am looking to make a project for a college club that involves setting up a Linux server (for webpages or a database) and accessing that server over a wireless connection.  However, I would like to know if it is possible to use an old desktop and a wireless router to set up a personal network that does not connect to the general Internet.

What I mean is: Can I configure a router (or even a simple wireless adapter) to broadcast a wireless network that serves merely to allow other computers to connect via WiFi to the server/desktop?  The wireless router would be hard-wired using Ethernet into a NIC on the desktop itself.  But neither the wireless router or server/desktop would be connected to the Internet.  Basically, I want to act as if the server/desktop *was* the Internet itself (as small as it would be, and possibly connecting another server/desktop to the new network if I can get one).

Can anyone give me advice on what I should be looking to do software- or hardware-wise to create this configuration?  I do not have a large budget, and would be using primarily older hardware (a few years old most likely).

(As mentioned previously, I do plan to use some Linux distribution for the server/desktop itself, as we cannot afford to use Windows for this project.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done.

You'll want to have a DHCP running, to give addresses to the computers that will visit the web server.  (I'm giving this advice based on using IPv4, which currently should work fine for most devices.)  A DHCP server is often built into most consumer routers, so that isn't likely to be a big problem.

Assign the web server an address that is in the same subnet as the devices that connect to the wireless device.  For instance, if you are using a /24 subnet (with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0), you have 256 addresses, ending with ".0" through ".255".  (e.g., 192.168.1.0 through 192.168.1.255.  I'm focusing mainly on the last octet.)

Actually, ".0" and ".255" have special purposes, so you have .1 through .254 available.  If you set your DHCP server to serve out addresses from .10 through .199, then you have tons more addresses than you're likely to use (unless your network is big enough that you probably should learn more about subnetting).  You may want to have your DHCP server reserve the IPv4 address that gets used by the web server.  You definitely don't want the DHCP server to hand out that IPv4 address to any other device.

A "gateway"  refers to a router that helps get traffic to a specific device.  The setting called the "default gateway" refers to the IPv4 address of a device that will get traffic onto the Internet (thereby getting traffic to any device, located anywhere on the Internet, unless there is a more specific route).  Since you don't want Internet access, you can leave this setting blank for your DHCP server.

To do what you mentioned, you will want to use some software called a "web server".  e.g., Apache, or nginx

For hardware: a 486+ is recommended.  So any full-sized computer/laptop made in the late 1990s or later will likely be fine.  (Actually, slightly better is recommended.  But something this old could likely work, at least with some Linux distributions.)  Clearly newer is better, so a 10 year old computer would be better than a 20 year old computer.  Unless you're looking at using some extremely old/underpowered equipment, you simply don't have a whole lot to need to worry about there.

Comment: I appreciate all of your advice.  Between your post and those of @cybernard I have a good idea of what I am trying to do now.  I believe I understand subnetting enough to get your advice to work for my purposes.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Any wireless router can do this.  Just don't plug a cable that goes to the internet into the router or the PC.  The wireless router will give out local IP address automatically.

Since the wireless router nor the PC can independently connect to the internet so any device that connect to your network would not get internet.  Now if another PC with a wireless and wired network jack was connected then the wireless would connect to you, but the user could plug the internet into the wired jack.  However, that still wouldn't give your network internet unless they turn on internet sharing and change settings on the router.